# Switching images during mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my code switch images during hover over certain images already placed. Does anyone know the solution? Here's the code:

```
.first-image {
    float: left;
}
.first-image:hover {
    background-image: url(0-1/0_Hover.png)
}
.second-image {
    float:right;
}
.second-image:hover {
    background-image: url(0-1/1_Hover.png)
}
```

_

```
<div class="first-image">
    <a href="https://bi-na-ri-es.com/black-white"><img src="0-1/0_No_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt=""/></a>
</div>

<div class="second-image">
    <img src="0-1/1_No_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way you can do with Jquery :

```js
 $('.first-image').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('second-image'); 
 });
 $('.second-image').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('first-image'); 
 });
```

```css
.wrapper {
 background-color: coral;
 width:200px;
 height: 100px;
}

.first-image {
    float: left;
}
.first-image:hover {
    background-image: url(0-1/0_Hover.png)
}
.second-image {
    float:right;
}
.second-image:hover {
    bac
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="first-image">
   <a href="https://bi-na-ri-es.com/black-white">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/cc/Googlewave.svg/1273px-Googlewave.svg.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
   </a>
 </div>

 <div class="second-image">
  <a href="https://bi-na-ri-es.com/black-white">
   <img src="https://santatracker.google.com/images/og.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the image toggle between each other. Is there an alternative to not having the images toggle between each other? I just need the image source changed to another image in my computer when the mouse hovers over one of the images

Answer (score 0):

You can put both images in the markup, hide the one you want to display on hover by default, and when you hover the parent, hide the visible image and show the hidden one.

```css
.first-image {
  float: left;
}
.second-image {
  float:right;
}
.hover, .parent:hover img:not(.hover) {
  display: none;
}
.parent:hover .hover {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* you don't need this - just for the demo */
.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-image parent">
  <a href="https://bi-na-ri-es.com/black-white">
    <img src="0-1/0_No_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt="">
    <img src="0-1/0-1/0_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt="" class="hover">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="second-image parent">
  <img src="0-1/1_No_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt="">
  <img src="0-1/1_Hover.png" width="946" height="1066" alt="" class="hover">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this, because no hover images in your divs are covering the background images. You can put transparent image in your div and make something like this:

```
.second-image {
    background-image: url(0-1/1_No_Hover.png)
}
.second-image:hover {
    background-image: url(0-1/1_Hover.png)
}

<div class="second-image">
    <img src="someTransparentImage" width="946" height="1066" alt=""/>
</div>
```

or you can just remove image from inside the div, and assing width or height for that div with the background image without hover and other image on hover

```
<div class="second-image">            
 </div>
```

and the css:

```
.second-image {
    width: 946px;
    height: 1066px;
    background-image: url(0-1/1_No_Hover.png)
}
.second-image:hover {
    background-image: url(0-1/1_Hover.png)
}
```

the same with first div

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/WilliamRobinson/nhyrhrg2/)

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/29/09/17/cat-300572_960_720.jpg);
}
.image:hover {
  background-image: url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/09/25/636104270517585477-986189690_maxresdefault.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript to switch image *sources* on hover.

However, you can use CSS to switch background images on hover, as you're set up to do here - just change your HTML and CSS a bit:

```css
.image {
  width: 946px;
  height: 1066px;
}

.first {
  float: left;
  background-image: url(0-1/0_No_Hover.png);
}

.first:hover {
  background-image: url(0-1/0_Hover.png);
  /*just for demo*/
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.second {
  float: right;
  background-image: url(0-1/1_No_Hover.png);
}

.second:hover {
  background-image: url(0-1/1_Hover.png);
  /*just for demo*/
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://bi-na-ri-es.com/black-white">
  <div class="first image"></div>
</a>

<div class="second image"></div>
```

> Note that in the past, wrapping `<div>` in an anchor tag was not acceptable. However, it is compliant in HTML5, so add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea why you want to do that but since I know the images appear based on their sources and every source shows one image. So changing the src will change the image anyway.
I guess probably by using a cover image, z-index and set time out it works but don't believe if it is really a good way to go !

```css
.wrapper {
 width:600px;
 height: 300px;
}

.first-image {
    float: left;
  background-image: url("http://mindfulness-praktijk.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/krulboom.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.first-image:hover {
    background-image: url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5H9Od8cBl9Y/Te0yRPoVRlI/AAAAAAAAAUQ/nvXOI-MNkAc/s1600/geboorte%252Buit%252Bplaatje.png");
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;

}
.second-image {
    float:right;
  background-image: url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5H9Od8cBl9Y/Te0yRPoVRlI/AAAAAAAAAUQ/nvXOI-MNkAc/s1600/geboorte%252Buit%252Bplaatje.png");
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.second-image:hover {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://mindfulness-praktijk.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/krulboom.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-image"></div>
   <div class="second-image"></div>
</div>
```